# How to make buttons on UIAlertView displaying in multiple lines?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I want to display a message using UIAlertView and there will be two buttons. As one of the buttons has a long name, It's not appropriate to display both of them in one line. I know that when there are more than two buttons, all of them will be displayed each in a row. How can I display these two buttons in two line?
Thanks.

Comment: For an idea on how subclassing of UIAlertView (as mentioned by MattyG) could look like, have a look at the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16526932/378977

Answer (score 1):

There is no officially documented way to do this.
UIAlertView is a subclass of UIView.  So you could traverse its subclasses to find the buttons, and transform their position and size.  This is probably a bad idea though.  If Apple changes it's implementation of the UIAlertView, it might break your code.  Your app might also be rejected for customizing the UIAlertView.  Eg see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410216/uithreepartbutton-text-unrecognized-selector/4411902#4411902).

Instead, you should consider changing the title of your button to be shorter, or create your custom UIView subclass that you present modally.